# React Navigation custom navigator transitions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I'm looking to create a Stack Navigator that can handle animating specific elements between 2 screens. [Fluid Transitions](https://github.com/fram-x/FluidTransitions/tree/master) looked like a library I could use, but it doesn't support `react-navigation` 5.X. If there's a package that has this functionality for react-navigation v5, that would be great.

However, if there is no current package for v5, I'd like to extend the `StackNavigator` to handle this kind of functionality. I've been able to remove the default animations for the `StackNavigator` with something similar to the following (where `transition` is a bool taken in the `options` prop for the `Stack.Screen`:

```
const CustomTransitionStackNavigator = ({
  initialRouteName,
  children,
  screenOptions,
  ...rest
}) => {
  if (descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].options.transition) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].render()}
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <StackView
      {...rest}
      descriptors={descriptors}
      navigation={navigation}
      state={state}
    />
  );
};
```

I'd like to be able to use a `Context` (or some other method) of passing the transition progress to the scene's descendants in order to handle the animations. Is there some way to get the transition progress in v5? Or would this `CustomTransitionStackNavigator` need to manage that state? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CardAnimationContext` or `useCardAnimation` (which is just a convenience wrapper for the first one) to get transition progress in a stack navigator.

For example:

```jsx
import { useCardAnimation } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

export const SomeScreen = () => {
  const { current } = useCardAnimation();

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        transform: [{ scale: current.progress }],
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

This feature seems to be undocumented at the moment, but you can check [TypeScript definitions](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/1f5fb5481aeab8ba871da6a9d14ec2e2e883ebd8/packages/stack/src/types.tsx#L486) to get some more information.